# Makefile that calls other Makefile relink, how can I fix it ?

Tags: makefile

I have this Makefile :

```
ZAPPY_SERVER    = zappy_server

ZAPPY_AI    = zappy_ai

ZAPPY_GUI   = zappy_gui

all:    $(ZAPPY_SERVER) $(ZAPPY_AI) $(ZAPPY_GUI)

    $(ZAPPY_SERVER):
        make -C server/ && cp server/zappy_server .

    $(ZAPPY_AI):
        make -C client/ && cp client/zappy_ai .

    $(ZAPPY_GUI):
        make -C gui/ && cp gui/zappy_gui .

    clean:
        make clean -C server/
        make clean -C client/
        make clean -C gui/

    fclean:
        make fclean -C server/ && rm $(ZAPPY_SERVER)
        make fclean -C gui/ && rm $(ZAPPY_GUI)
        make fclean -C client/ && rm $(ZAPPY_AI)
```

But when I call `make` then `make clean` and then `make` , it relinks :

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

And I want to compile the sources of others Makefiles again. An idea of how to do so ?

Comment: Sometimes "Nothing to be done for all" error can be caused by spaces before command in makefile rule instead of tab. Please ensure that you use tabs instead of spaces inside of your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clean` rule does not remove the files `zappy_server`, `zappy_ai` and `zappy_gui`. And those files are the prerequisites of `all` (and the `all` rule has no commands), so the second time you ask Make to execute the `all` rule, Make tells you that there is nothing to be done.

If you want `clean` to remove those files, add a line to the `clean` recipe:

```
rm $(ZAPPY_SERVER) $(ZAPPY_AI) $(ZAPPY_GUI)
```

If you *don't* want `clean` to remove those files, but you still want Make to rebuild them, one way to do it is by declaring those targets [PHONY](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets):

```
.PHONY: $(ZAPPY_SERVER) $(ZAPPY_AI) $(ZAPPY_GUI)
```